# Speech to text enabling in unity not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, wikitude

I am using unity 2018.1.0f2 and windows 10. Below is the code.

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Windows.Speech;
public class Dinovoice : MonoBehaviour {
    KeywordRecognizer KeywordRecognizerObj;
    void Start () {
      string[] keywords_array={"Jump","Run"};
      KeywordRecognizerObj= new KeywordRecognizer(keywords_array);
      KeywordRecognizerObj.OnPhraseRecognized += KeywordRecognizer_OnPhraseRecognized;
      KeywordRecognizerObj.Start();
      Debug.Log("Started");
    }
    void Update() {

    }
    private void KeywordRecognizer_OnPhraseRecognized(PhraseRecognizedEventArgs args)
    {
       Debug.Log("Ended");
   }
}
```

When I run from unity Started is getting printed.Ended is not getting printed at all when I speak.I am using unity with wikitude. I am adding this script to my prefab.Can you please help me out.Is there any setting I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: It's unlikely to help, but you can try amending to `new KeywordRecognizer(keywords_array, ConfidenceLevel.Low)` for a higher recognition chance. In our app where we also use KeywordRecognizer, a number of people report that it won't work on their system for some reason.

Comment: I tried amending the code.But it dosen't work.I will try some other speech to text methods.Thanks a lot for a quick reply.

Comment: I tried another speech to text method.The api when used in chatbot is converting speech to text and working through postman.When tried from unity its not working.Any setting that has to be done in unity?